# MySQL 5.7 query without ROW_NUMBER to get DISTINCT values for one column not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the below code snippet to pull distinct values of 'username' from the table 'quiz_scores' which has username, score, and time for a set of quizzes.  I'm trying to pull just the best score for each user from the quiz titled 'sportsquiz' using MySQL 5.7.3 - which doesn't have the ROW_NUMBER function which I'd would otherwise use with PARTITION.

The code seems to work just fine as I have it below however it is sorting the results based on username A-Z.  I want it to sort based on score DESC then time ASC without sorting based on username - i.e. I want the top score for each user sorted by score, not by user.

Sample Data

| username | Score | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 50 | 1:05 |
| Bob | 47 | 1:25 |
| Judy | 49 | 1:42 |
| Bob | 49 | 1:13 |
| John | 50 | 1:25 |
| Judy | 50 | 1:59 |

Results wanted:

| username | Score | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 50 | 1:05 |
| Judy | 50 | 1:59 |
| Bob | 49 | 1:13 |

Results Displayed With Current Code:

| username | Score | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 50 | 1:05 |
| John | 50 | 1:25 |
| Judy | 50 | 1:59 |
| Bob | 49 | 1:13 |
| Judy | 49 | 1:42 |
| Bob | 47 | 1:25 |

When I remove the 'username ASC' from the ORDER BY I get all scores for all users, i.e. the rn rownumber variable isn't working anymore - I believe maybe I need to have username in ORDER BY for it to work?  Even if I put username ASC at the end of the ORDER BY list it still pulls all scores for all users instead of just the top score.  Scores are sorted based on 'score' first then on 'time' - so a score of 50 with a time of 2:30 is better than a score of 49 with a time of 1:30.

```
SELECT username,
       score,
       time  
FROM (
       SELECT *, IF(@prev <> username, @rn:=0,@rn), @prev:=username, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn
       FROM quiz_scores, (SELECT @rn:=0) rn, (SELECT @prev:='') prev
       WHERE quiz_id = 'sportsquiz'
       ORDER BY username ASC, score DESC, time ASC
     ) t 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags. Also I highly recommend providing sample data and desired results for clarity.

Comment: `ORDER BY  score DESC,username ASC,time ASC`

Comment: Please give us your table definitions and sample data.

Comment: You're really using MySQL 5.7.3? That was from 2013, it was a development milestone, almost two years prior to the first GA release of 5.7. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/ for the release history.

Comment: @BillKarwin yeah unfortunately - trying to get host to upgrade to 8.0 but looking for a fix in meantime.

Comment: If they haven't upgraded in nine years — even to the GA release of 5.7 — I would get a different hosting provider.

Comment: If you want your resultset ordered you have to apply an order by clause after your final `where`, the existing clause operates only on an intermediate resultset.

Comment: @Stu that's it I think thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY username ORDER BY username ASC, score DESC, time ASC) AS row_num
```